# Netlogo - How to get energy value for each fish

Tags: netlogo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z49Rk.jpg)

hello, can anyone help me on how to get the energy values for each fish. I want to graph it later but i'm having a hard time getting the energy value per fish. (Planning to do this on a large scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have a `fish` breed with an `energy` variable, getting the energy for each fish is simply:

```
[ energy ] of fish
```

This will give you a list of energy values, in random order.

As for plotting it, it depends on what kind of plot you want. A common possibility is an histogram, for which you would simply define your plot pen command as:

```
histogram [ energy ] of fish
```

If you need anything more specific than that, you will have to tell us what it is so we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! This really helped me a lot.